# How to calculate remaining days?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
private long calculateRemainingDays() {


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(2015, 7, 23);
        final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        final long millis = c.getTimeInMillis()
                - today.getTimeInMillis();
        // Convert to days
        final long days = millis / 86400000;
        return days;
}
```

I need to add a function in my android application. I want a remaining days from current day to 2015/9/30. When the date is change to next day, the remaining days will decrease. I would like to say like that: 
7 days remaining... 6/5/4/etc... Please help me to get correct remaining days. Sorry for my poor english. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Calender.JULY` instead of `7` in the parameters for the `set()` method.

`7 = August.`
`6 = July.`

As it starts with `January` as `0`. It's better to use the static instance variables like `Calender.JANUARY`.

But as you want to calculate till `2015/9/30`, you should set the value as

```
c.set(2015, Calender.SEPTEMBER, 09);
```

The rest of the code seems ok. It will return the correct number of days.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using `joda.time`

you can do something of this form:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2015, Calender.SEPTEMBER, 30);
Date endDate = c.getTime();
Instant startInstant = new Instant(new Date());
Instant endInstant = new Instant(endDate);
Days days = Days.daysBetween(startInstant, endInstant);
```

Comment: how to use joda.time?

Comment: `import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.Instant;`

Comment: how to make endDate? My end date is 2015/9/30.

Comment: `final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.set(2015, Calender.SEPTEMBER, 30);Date endDate = c.getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
final long millis = c.getTimeInMillis()
                - today.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println ("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(millis , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```